# Make querySelector in kotlin-js more convenient and type-safe

Tags: kotlin

I'd like you to take a look at those extension functions I made in kotlinjs (version 1.3.61):

```
inline fun <reified E : Element> Element.queryHtmlSelectorOrNull(selectors: String): E? {
    return this.querySelector(selectors = selectors) as E?
}

inline fun <reified E : Element> Element.queryHtmlSelector(selectors: String): E {
    return this.queryHtmlSelectorOrNull(selectors = selectors)
        ?: error("couldn't find element by selectors '$selectors'")
}
```

Now let me elaborate. I was using classic javascript [querySelector](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/org.w3c.dom/-document/query-selector.html). This signature:

```
fun querySelector(selectors: String): Element?
```

Has some downsides/qualities:

- It is optional.
- When I force cast to for example `HTMLDivElement` and result is actually null, I get `NullPointerException` with no additional information/error message. Example:

  ```
  document.querySelector(".something-non-existent") as HTMLDivElement //throws
  ```
- I have to explicitly cast my query to specific element I want (example `HTMLDivElement?` or `HTMLDivElement`).

My functions fix some of the issues, but create new issues:

- You can explicitly select what type you need or compiler can guess it based on variable type.

  Example:

  ```
  document.queryHtmlSelector<HTMLDivElement>(".something")
  ```

  or

  ```
  val element: HTMLDivElement = document.queryHtmlSelector(".something")
  ```

The downside is that this doesn't work (need to set type explicitly):

```
val element = document.queryHtmlSelector(".something")
```

I would be cool somehow to "default" base type to `Element` if none is specified, but can't think of way to do that.

I'd like something that can pretty much replace original function and just add benefits of stronger typing and nicer error message. Any hints on how to improve this are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which Kotlin version are you using?

Comment: Currently `1.3.61`, but targeting latest.

Comment: The usage of `reified`, do you have that to get any potential ClassCastExceptions earlier, or any other reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Would be cool somehow, to "default" base type to Element if none is specified, but can't think of way to do that."* Indeed it is not possible to do that, at least not with the same method. An option could be to have a separate method for that. `document.queryHtmlSelectorRaw` ? Or wait, actually... That leaves you back to what you were starting with, `Element.querySelector`.

> I'd like something, that can pretty much replace original function and just add benefits of stronger typing and nicer error message. Any hints on how to improve this are greatly appreciated.

Given those requirements, I'd say that the current methods is about as good as you're gonna get. You have the stronger typing (but you will have to specify it). You have the better error message if it's null.

The only things that I would consider are:

- Get rid of `reified`, I'm not convinced that you need it.
- Change method names, `queryHtmlSelector` can easily be confused with the built in `querySelector`. May I recommend just the name `selector` or `select`?
- Improve the error message even further, such as `No element found using selector '$selector' on $this`.